# Get generated key from column organized table in DB2 Warehouse

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2

I am not able to get generated key from column organized table from an INSERT SQL statement run against IBM DB2 warehouse. I am using Java and JDBC driver. Everything works fine - I am able to connect to DB, create tables, insert data, I am just not able to get a generated key if it is generated in column organized table. Note that row organized tables work fine and return the key properly.

Consider a table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id       INTEGER not null GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
   username VARCHAR(16),
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

If this is row organized table I am able to get the generated key fine by using:

```
PreparedStatement pr = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

However, If this is column organized table the PreparedStatemnt creation fails with an error:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1667, SQLSTATE=42858, SQLERRMC=BLUADMIN.USERS;ORGANIZE BY COLUMN;FINAL|NEW|OLD TABLE, DRIVER=4.25.13
```

Even if I specify columns I want to get returned like so:

```
PreparedStatement pr = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(?)", new String[]{"id","username"});

pr.setString(1, "test");
pr.executeUpdate();
```

I get

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1667, SQLSTATE=42858, SQLERRMC=BLUADMIN.USERS;ORGANIZE BY COLUMN;FINAL|NEW|OLD TABLE, DRIVER=4.25.13
```

on line `pr.executeUpdate();`.

Does this mean that it is not possible to get generated key from column organized table from the INSERT statement in DB2 Warehouse?

Comment: What are the full SQL statements, e.g., used in `insertStatementSql`?

Comment: Hi @data_henrik :-) It is `INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(?)`. I think it might actually not be possible.

Comment: Have you tried the [`identity_val_local()` function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFMBX/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004231.html)?

Comment: That seems like a nifty little useful function. I am using batch inserts though so not sure how it will behave with those. I want to use this generated key as a foreign key in other inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently shipping versions v11.1.x and V11.5.x will throw SQL1667N when the query sent to Db2 uses 'FINAL TABLE' or 'OLD TABLE', or 'NEW TABLE' clauses for a **column organized** table.

When you use the jdbc syntax `PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`, this syntax may be used under the covers.

Currently those clauses are not supported (i.e. will cause the exception to be thrown) for ORGANIZE BY COLUMN tables.  There are other restrictions on column organized tables that you should be aware of before using them.

You can workaround this by creating your tables explicitly with the `ORGANIZE BY ROW` clause.

Comment: However if I do use `ORGANIZE BY ROW` the table will not be using `BLU ACCEL` right?

Comment: That is correct. BLU acceleration works for column organized tables.  The kind of row by row processing associated with single-row inserts (for which you seek the autogenerated surrogate key) is more associated with OLTP workloads. Remember you can always populate (some columns of) your column-organized-table from a row-organized table .

Comment: Another option would be to use a SEQUENCE, and get the NEXT VAL FOR from the sequence before using it in your INSERTs.

Comment: You can also request or vote for an enhancement here https://ibm-data-and-ai.ideas.aha.io/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried actually selecting the generated ID? Try something like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM FINAL TABLE
    (INSERT INTO users(username) VALUES(?))
```

See "[Retrieval of result sets from an SQL data change statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0011133.html)" in the IBM Db2 documentation.

Comment: But that will run another SELECT statement. I have no doubts this will work. I am able to select this Id with a sub-sequent request. This just seems like adding more delay when using this as a foreign key in different tables.

Comment: No, it is designed for exactly the purpose as described by you. Integrating two actions into a single execution